# How to use Google App Scripts to search a Google Document for a specific word?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a Google Scripts function that can search a designated Google Document for a specific string of words? Or any way to do that? I am trying to make a conditional statement that will find a word in a Google Document, and if that word exists, it will carry out a task. Thank you.

An example:

if (for example, the word gym exists in the Google Document){
     Send an email to the gym teacher.
    }

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need. I commented out some of the Logger stuff but left it there in case you wanted to see how things worked more clearly.

```
function findText() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();//get doc
  var body = doc.getBody().getText();//get text as string
  //Logger.log(body);
  var regex = /gym/g;//look for 'gym'
  var searchSuccess = body.search(regex);
  Logger.log(searchSuccess);
  if(searchSuccess > 0){
    Logger.log('Item Found')
  } else {
    Logger.log('Item not found')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`findText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body.html#findText(String)). For example:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
if(body.findText("gym"))
{
    // send an email
}
```